# Transistor gets too hot, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: transistors, pcb, circuit-design, diodes, pwm

I am very, very new to circuit design.

I have designed a [PWM circuit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LXCB9GC) to control the flow rate of a small diaphragm pump. Prior to making this PCB I have demoed this setup on a solderless breadboard with everything but the diodes. When I plugged in the pump, I noticed that the transistor would get really hot and start smoking.

I consulted an electrical engineer, who told me that I needed a TVS and Schottky diode to protect the transistor from current spikes and backflow, respectively. I incorporated these into the breadboard circuit and the transistor no longer heated up.

I decided I was ready to transfer this design to a PCB. Once I assembled everything and powered it up, again, the transistor heated up immediately and started smoking.

I'm feeling discouraged since I triple-checked every datasheet to make sure that all parts worked with each other, and used the KiCad inspection tools to make sure that all the connections were laid out correctly. But, I will say, I'm sure there are key items missing from this mental checklist, which is why I'm here.

I have attached screenshots of the BOM, schematic, and PCB layout. In addition to fixing the error in my circuit, I am open to any suggestions on what I can add/swap out to improve the circuit's longevity.

Transistor datasheet: [IRLML2060TRPbF](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlml2060pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535664b7fb25ee)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Some wires are a little "thin" ... What is the nominal current pump ?

Comment: @Antonio51 300mA

Comment: Need also a decoupling capacitor (1-10 uF or more) on 12 V.

Comment: Can you use a multimeter to measure the actual current used by the pump? (10A range, just connect pump to 12V power supply via meter)

Comment: @Antonio51 I'll add that in, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you have D3 installed correctly? If it were reversed it would connect 12V directly to FET and burn it up. The part should have a stripe on one end and that's the cathode, to pin 1 of your jacks.

Comment: What frequency?

Comment: @bobflux the current seems behave in a wave-like manner, oscillating between 200 mA and 1.2 A.

Comment: @td127 in fact I do not have D3 installed correctly... just out of curiosity can you elaborate more on what happens when it's installed in reverse? is it basically behaving as if there's a plain wire connected?

Comment: @tim-williams not sure, I bought this pump off amazon. it doesn't come with a datasheet.

Comment: Which exact Arduino model is that? Does the MCU run at 3.3V or 5V? Have  you measured if high GPIOs are 5V or 3.3V? What code the MCU is running, is the pin an output?

Comment: Yeah so if your multimeter says between 200mA and 1.2A the motor is probably drawing a lot more than the 300mA "amazon specification"

Comment: @bobflux true, but the transistor can handle up to 30A.

Comment: @Justme 5V for both. The pin is an output. MCU is controlled by python (via firmata).

Comment: No, what PWM are you driving it at? Show code?

Comment: @duckfoot99 The Arduino Nano is 3.3V AFAIK, plus you clearly have a 3.3V pin on the schematic.  Did you actually measure 5V on the GPIO or are you assuming?  Driving the gate at only 3.3V will greatly increase resistance, making it very hot.

Answer (score 3):

From the transistor [datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlml2060pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535664b7fb25ee) in the question:

[image]

It's driven from a 5 V arduino GPIO, so let's go with 0.5 Ω R<sub>DS(on)</sub>

P = R·I<sup>2</sup>:

```
I = 0.3 A    P = 0.045 W
I = 1.0 A    P = 0.5   W
```

Predicted temperature rise above ambient is the product of power (W) and thermal resistance junction to ambient (R<sub>thJA</sub>). It's a rather tiny transistor...

[image]

There is the usual footnote:

[image]

But you don't have 1 in² copper, so instead you will get the usual thermal resistance of SOT23 which is around 250-500°C/W.

So the transistor should get 20°C hotter than ambient at 0.3 A, but at 1 A (or more, which you measured on your motor), it could be 125-250°C hotter than ambient, so it smokes.

Solution: pick a MOSFET with a much lower R<sub>DS(on)</sub>.

Answer (score 1):

You said the diode D3 was reversed.

It will basically equal to a short circuit, which the transistor cannot handle.

Comment: Hypothetically, what if I replace that diode with a wire? would the circuit still work?

Comment: @duckfoot99 No. It will be a short circuit, and transistor will burn up.

Comment: got it. thanks!